# waitbar -> length ot the bar figure?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

This is probably something trivial, but how can I control the width of the bar figure inside the waitbar ?

My problem is, that when I use the 'Position' property, I can expand only the waitbar, but not simultaneously the bar figure inside it.

So, how is this made ?

```
hWaitb = waitbar(0,'Titel','Position',[x y width height]);
```

Than probably I would make

```
childrenWaitb = get(hWaitb, 'Children');
```

but what then?

Comment: ok, I got it, probably I should delete the question, but in case anybody is interested:

    childrenWaitb = get(hWaitb, 'Children'); 
    set(childrenWaitb, 'Postiion',[xWait yWait widthBarFigure heightBarFigure]); 

Best,

Comment: Don't delete, answer yourself! Save for the next generations

Comment: @HeinrichStack, its perfectly acceptable to answer, and then accept the answer on your own question. :)

Answer (score 1):

The OP found the solution himself, see comments above:

```
childrenWaitb = get(hWaitb, 'Children'); 
set(childrenWaitb, 'Position',[xWait yWait widthBarFigure heightBarFigure]);
```